My postgresql indexes are read slowly from disk
I have a database of sufficient size that it does not fit entirely in RAM, including indexes that also exceed RAM capacity. When performing queries, I observe significant differences in processing time depending on whether the index needs to be read from disk or is already loaded in RAM. I have confirmed using EXPLAIN ANALYZE that the issue stems from index scans. See for example :

https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/2c85077gagh98a17 : very slow because some part of the index is "read" (from disk) and not "hit".
https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/gfd20f8cadaa5261#plan/node/8 : instantaneous, when everything is in RAM.

I measured the speed of loading my index into RAM during a query, which is approximately 2 MB/s. However, my infrastructure theoretically supports disk read speeds of around 900 MB/s.
This issue appears related to the index itself rather than a disk read speed cap. For instance, when I execute 2 parallel queries on different tables, the disk read speed reaches 4 MB/s. Yet, when I execute 2 parallel queries on the same table, my disk read remains at 2 MB/s.
My question is : what can I change to reach an index reading speed from disk of 900 Mo/s ?
I am working within an Azure VM environment. If additional information is required, I am available to provide it.
Environment :

P80 disks
Postgresql 12
VM E16s_v3

The partitioned table mentioned in the first plan more or less follows this DDL
-- public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" definition

-- Drop table

-- DROP TABLE public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1";

CREATE TABLE public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" (
    "ID_TRAIN" int4 NOT NULL,
    "ID_JOUR" int4 NOT NULL,
    "ID_LEG" int4 NOT NULL,
    "JX" int4 NOT NULL,
    "RES" int4 NULL,
    "REV" float8 NULL,
    "CAPA" int4 NULL,
    "OFFRE" int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_TRAIN", "ID_JOUR", "ID_LEG", "JX")
)
PARTITION BY RANGE ("ID_JOUR");
CREATE INDEX "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_ID_JOUR_JX_idx" ON ONLY public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" USING btree ("ID_JOUR", "JX");
CREATE INDEX "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_ID_JOUR_idx" ON ONLY public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" USING btree ("ID_JOUR");
CREATE INDEX "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_ID_LEG_idx" ON ONLY public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" USING btree ("ID_LEG");
CREATE INDEX "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_ID_TRAIN_idx" ON ONLY public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" USING btree ("ID_TRAIN");
CREATE INDEX "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_JX_idx" ON ONLY public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" USING btree ("JX");


-- public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" foreign keys

ALTER TABLE public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" ADD CONSTRAINT "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_ID_JOUR_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_JOUR") REFERENCES public."D_JOUR"("ID_JOUR");
ALTER TABLE public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" ADD CONSTRAINT "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_ID_LEG_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_LEG") REFERENCES public."D_OD"("ID_OD");
ALTER TABLE public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" ADD CONSTRAINT "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_ID_TRAIN_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_TRAIN") REFERENCES public."D_TRAIN"("ID_TRAIN");
ALTER TABLE public."F_TDLJ_HIST_1" ADD CONSTRAINT "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_JX_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("JX") REFERENCES public."D_JX"("JX");

The first explain analyze plan is the "whole plan", I directly targeted a specific partition, under conditions on columns "ID_TRAIN", "ID_JOUR", "JX"
Here is another query and plan. I am not directly selecting "ID_TRAIN", but the final index scan is the same:
300K via index scan, query:
set track_io_timing=TRUE;
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)(
    select "ID_TRAIN", "ID_JOUR", "JX", "ID_LEG", "RES", "REV" from "F_TDLJ_HIST" fth
    inner join "D_TRAIN" using ("ID_TRAIN")
    inner join "D_ENTNAT" using ("ID_ENTNAT")
    where "ENTITY" = 'LOIREPARIS' and "ID_JOUR" between 4770 and 4820 and "JX" between -92 and 1
);

300K via index scan, plan:
Nested Loop  (cost=2.63..18455.74 rows=44545 width=28) (actual time=51.034..645739.307 rows=304556 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=86297 read=215554
  I/O Timings: read=642144.906
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.07..60.13 rows=35 width=4) (actual time=0.128..1.656 rows=272 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=71
        ->  Index Scan using "UX_ENTNAT" on "D_ENTNAT"  (cost=0.27..2.49 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.051..0.054 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (("ENTITY")::text = 'LOIREPARIS'::text)
              Buffers: shared hit=3
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "D_TRAIN"  (cost=1.80..57.11 rows=53 width=8) (actual time=0.073..1.356 rows=272 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: ("ID_ENTNAT" = "D_ENTNAT"."ID_ENTNAT")
              Heap Blocks: exact=65
              Buffers: shared hit=68
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "fki_D_TRAIN_ID_ENTNAT_fkey"  (cost=0.00..1.78 rows=53 width=0) (actual time=0.037..0.037 rows=272 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ("ID_ENTNAT" = "D_ENTNAT"."ID_ENTNAT")
                    Buffers: shared hit=3
  ->  Index Scan using "F_TDLJ_HIST_p4770_pkey" on "F_TDLJ_HIST_p4770" fth  (cost=0.56..436.98 rows=8861 width=28) (actual time=3.560..2373.034 rows=1120 loops=272)
        Index Cond: (("ID_TRAIN" = "D_TRAIN"."ID_TRAIN") AND ("ID_JOUR" >= 4770) AND ("ID_JOUR" <= 4820) AND ("JX" >= '-92'::integer) AND ("JX" <= 1))
        Buffers: shared hit=86226 read=215554
        I/O Timings: read=642144.906
Settings: effective_cache_size = '96GB', effective_io_concurrency = '200', max_parallel_workers_per_gather = '4', random_page_cost = '1.1', search_path = 'public', work_mem = '64MB'
Planning Time: 183.240 ms
Execution Time: 645858.500 ms

I tried requesting more data to make it switch to a sequential scan. Here, getting 20M rows instead of 300K takes approximately the same time :
20M via index scan, query:
set track_io_timing=TRUE; 
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)(
    select "ID_TRAIN", "ID_JOUR", "JX", "ID_LEG", "RES", "REV" from "F_TDLJ_HIST" fth
    inner join "D_TRAIN" using ("ID_TRAIN")
    inner join "D_ENTNAT" using ("ID_ENTNAT")
    where "ID_JOUR" between 4770 and 4820 and "JX" between -92 and 1
    -- removed filter on "ID_TRAIN", but ofc forgot to remove the joins..
);

20M via index scan, plan
Hash Join  (cost=975.41..6710886.53 rows=15881782 width=28) (actual time=243.368..764675.784 rows=17267213 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: ("D_TRAIN"."ID_ENTNAT" = "D_ENTNAT"."ID_ENTNAT")
  Buffers: shared hit=252195 read=5575770
  I/O Timings: read=730384.999
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=950.71..6668739.11 rows=15881782 width=32) (actual time=13.909..760404.410 rows=17267213 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (fth."ID_TRAIN" = "D_TRAIN"."ID_TRAIN")
        Buffers: shared hit=252180 read=5575770
        I/O Timings: read=730384.999
        ->  Seq Scan on "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_p4770" fth  (cost=0.00..6626086.32 rows=15881782 width=28) (actual time=6.084..754077.855 rows=17267213 loops=1)
              Filter: (("ID_JOUR" >= 4770) AND ("ID_JOUR" <= 4820) AND ("JX" >= '-92'::integer) AND ("JX" <= 1))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 22567684
              Buffers: shared hit=251550 read=5575770
              I/O Timings: read=730384.999
        ->  Hash  (cost=772.54..772.54 rows=14254 width=8) (actual time=7.688..7.690 rows=14254 loops=1)
              Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 685kB
              Buffers: shared hit=630
              ->  Seq Scan on "D_TRAIN"  (cost=0.00..772.54 rows=14254 width=8) (actual time=0.069..5.492 rows=14254 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=630
  ->  Hash  (cost=19.59..19.59 rows=408 width=4) (actual time=229.387..229.388 rows=408 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 23kB
        Buffers: shared hit=12
        ->  Index Only Scan using "D_ENTNAT_pkey1" on "D_ENTNAT"  (cost=0.27..19.59 rows=408 width=4) (actual time=0.019..0.190 rows=408 loops=1)
              Heap Fetches: 0
              Buffers: shared hit=12
Settings: effective_cache_size = '96GB', effective_io_concurrency = '200', max_parallel_workers_per_gather = '4', random_page_cost = '1.1', search_path = 'public', work_mem = '64MB'
Planning Time: 3.351 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 17
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 1.732 ms, Inlining 62.117 ms, Optimization 97.389 ms, Emission 69.264 ms, Total 230.502 ms
Execution Time: 765721.071 ms

20M via seq scan, query:
set track_io_timing=TRUE; 
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)(
    select "ID_TRAIN", "ID_JOUR", "JX", "ID_LEG", "RES", "REV" from "F_TDLJ_HIST_1" fth
    inner join "D_TRAIN" using ("ID_TRAIN")
    inner join "D_ENTNAT" using ("ID_ENTNAT")
    where "ID_JOUR" between 4770 and 4820 and "JX" between -92 and 1
);

20M via seq scan, plan:
Hash Join  (cost=975.41..6710886.53 rows=15881782 width=28) (actual time=243.368..764675.784 rows=17267213 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: ("D_TRAIN"."ID_ENTNAT" = "D_ENTNAT"."ID_ENTNAT")
  Buffers: shared hit=252195 read=5575770
  I/O Timings: read=730384.999
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=950.71..6668739.11 rows=15881782 width=32) (actual time=13.909..760404.410 rows=17267213 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (fth."ID_TRAIN" = "D_TRAIN"."ID_TRAIN")
        Buffers: shared hit=252180 read=5575770
        I/O Timings: read=730384.999
        ->  Seq Scan on "F_TDLJ_HIST_1_OLDP_p4770" fth  (cost=0.00..6626086.32 rows=15881782 width=28) (actual time=6.084..754077.855 rows=17267213 loops=1)
              Filter: (("ID_JOUR" >= 4770) AND ("ID_JOUR" <= 4820) AND ("JX" >= '-92'::integer) AND ("JX" <= 1))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 22567684
              Buffers: shared hit=251550 read=5575770
              I/O Timings: read=730384.999
        ->  Hash  (cost=772.54..772.54 rows=14254 width=8) (actual time=7.688..7.690 rows=14254 loops=1)
              Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 685kB
              Buffers: shared hit=630
              ->  Seq Scan on "D_TRAIN"  (cost=0.00..772.54 rows=14254 width=8) (actual time=0.069..5.492 rows=14254 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=630
  ->  Hash  (cost=19.59..19.59 rows=408 width=4) (actual time=229.387..229.388 rows=408 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 23kB
        Buffers: shared hit=12
        ->  Index Only Scan using "D_ENTNAT_pkey1" on "D_ENTNAT"  (cost=0.27..19.59 rows=408 width=4) (actual time=0.019..0.190 rows=408 loops=1)
              Heap Fetches: 0
              Buffers: shared hit=12
Settings: effective_cache_size = '96GB', effective_io_concurrency = '200', max_parallel_workers_per_gather = '4', random_page_cost = '1.1', search_path = 'public', work_mem = '64MB'
Planning Time: 3.351 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 17
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 1.732 ms, Inlining 62.117 ms, Optimization 97.389 ms, Emission 69.264 ms, Total 230.502 ms
Execution Time: 765721.071 ms


Not sure what your question is, but please consider reading this advice

Thanks, i edited my question, is it clearer ?

I see "Azure", so unless you pay a lot of money, disk performance will be bad, which explains what you are seeing.

Not very, as you didn't provide the table or index definition, nor the entire plan. The fact that your block devices claim to deliver up to 900 Mb/s sequential read throughput, doesn't mean they are capable of doing nearly as well with random I/O.

Thanks, I tried to add more details. How can I check if the index is accessed through a random I/O ? How can I physically reorder my index to allow a sequential read ? I already tried CLUSTER and REINDEX

@LaurenzAlbe I am actually paying some money to get the best disk available (P80), I do not know if I can do something manually (e.g. physical reordering on disk) to get better performances or if it is entirely in Azure hand.

I would have a look at it, but I cannot read Dalibo's plan obfuscator.

@LaurenzAlbe I am not sure what you mean by "Dalibo's plan obfuscator", so here is all the infos I can give you on the replayed query of the first Dalibo's link :

query raw plan : https://pastebin.com/tqnFCVrm
query : https://pastebin.com/uQL75AYK
dalibo's explainer : https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/846cba2f06cbgfag


What I mean is that I cannot deal with Dalibo's explain tool. You should enable track_io_timing to get information about the I/O performance. I suggest that you run EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) and add the raw output to the question. No JSON, please.

Ok, I ran the query and uploaded the output !

For each entry found in the normal index scan there is a lookup in the heap which is a random read measured in IOPS. Sequential I/O takes roughly only 25% of random I/O timing. In your case since you set random_page_cost=1.1 (recommended for SSDs) it's forced to use index scan over sequential scan. If you were using default=4 all the above queries could have been sequential scans. Probabaly what you are looking for is bitmap index scan which is mix of both random read and sequential read. It only works when there is too much contiguous blocks for random read but too little for sequential read. Did you try vacuuming ?
If any of your indexed columns have natural ordering then you may test with BRIN index which is compact and faster compared to regular B-Tree .
